# List to group of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list like

```
A = [1,10,50,100,500]
```

I need to group by 2 numbers with proper sequence. Output is like this,

```
B = [(1,9),(10,49),(50,99),(100,499)]
```

I have tried via `yield`:

```
def group(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        val = lst[i:i+n]
        if len(val) == n:
            yield tuple(val)

print(list(group([1,10,50,100,500], 2)))
```

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using `bisect` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `zip` the sequence with itself (without the first item):

```
A = [1,10,50,100,500]

def group(lst):
    for i, j in zip(A, A[1:]):  # pairwise items
        yield (i, j-1)          # decrement second item by 1

>>> list(group(A))
[(1, 9), (10, 49), (50, 99), (100, 499)]
```

Or use it as list-comprehension without intermediate function:

```
>>> [(i, j-1) for i, j in zip(A, A[1:])]
[(1, 9), (10, 49), (50, 99), (100, 499)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension with [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate pairwise over the list:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> A = [1,10,50,100,500]
>>> [(x, y - 1) for x, y in zip(A, islice(A, 1, None))]
[(1, 9), (10, 49), (50, 99), (100, 499)]
```

In above `islice` returns an iterator that starts from the second element on `A`. `islice` is used instead of normal slicing so that the original list doesn't need to be copied:

```
>>> s = list(islice(A, 1, None))
>>> s
[10, 50, 100, 500]
```

Then `zip` is used to create iterable pairs of items from the original list and iterator:

```
>>> pairs = list(zip(A, s))
>>> pairs
[(1, 10), (10, 50), (50, 100), (100, 500)]
```

And finally list comprehension iterates over the pairs to create the result:

```
>>> [(x, y - 1) for x, y in pairs]
[(1, 9), (10, 49), (50, 99), (100, 499)]
```